# WP8.1 App Version Changed on Store

Tags: 8.1, store

We have a WP8.1 app which has a package version of '1.2.0.38', but when it's published to the windows store, it shows a version around '2015.X.XX.XXXX'.

I don't have any clue about it, the version is also double checked in the release wizard.

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you see this other version number? In the store?

Comment: @Thomas : Yes, the details tab in the store.

Comment: You'll probably get a better response on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is the default store behaviour. It creates an app version according to the current date and certain other parameters. But if you install the app and see the appversion then it would be same as the one you have mentioned.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910934/wrong-version-number-submitted-to-windows-phone-store-is-it-possible-to-correct
See this post for more help.